# Redefining the Russian dash to have unbreakable space after it

Tags: spacing, babel

Russian dash invoked via `"---` has unbreable space before it, while sometimes I want to have unbreakable space also after it, e. g. if it preceeds a number, like `... "--- 1`.

To achieve this I take the definition of `\cdash` from `babel`, and change it to

```
\def\cdash#1#2#3{\def\tempx@{#3}%
\def\tempa@{-}\def\tempb@{~}\def\tempc@{*}\def\tempd@{=}%
 \ifx\tempx@\tempa@\@Acdash\else
  \ifx\tempx@\tempb@\@Bcdash\else
   \ifx\tempx@\tempc@\@Ccdash\else
    \ifx\tempx@\tempd@\@Dcdash\else
    \errmessage{Wrong usage of cdash}\fi\fi\fi\fi}
\def\@Acdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Bcdash{\leavevmode\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi
 \nobreak\cyrdash\penalty\exhyphenpenalty\hskip\z@skip\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Ccdash{\leavevmode
 \nobreak\cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.35em\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Dcdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}
```

I have added `\ifx\tempx@\tempd@\@Dcdash\else` and defined

```
\def\@Dcdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}
```

So now `"--=` should be identical to `"---`, but with unbreakable space.

But I get the following error

```
! Wrong usage of cdash.
\cdash ...\else \errmessage {Wrong usage of cdash}
                                                  \fi \fi \fi
l.38            ╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В "--=
                       ╨╝╨╕╤А
?
```

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{russian}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX}

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Georgia}

\makeatletter

\def\cdash#1#2#3{\def\tempx@{#3}%
\def\tempa@{-}\def\tempb@{~}\def\tempc@{*}\def\tempd@{=}%
 \ifx\tempx@\tempa@\@Acdash\else
  \ifx\tempx@\tempb@\@Bcdash\else
   \ifx\tempx@\tempc@\@Ccdash\else
    \ifx\tempx@\tempd@\@Dcdash\else
    \errmessage{Wrong usage of cdash}\fi\fi\fi\fi}
\def\@Acdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Bcdash{\leavevmode\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi
 \nobreak\cyrdash\penalty\exhyphenpenalty\hskip\z@skip\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Ccdash{\leavevmode
 \nobreak\cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.35em\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Dcdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}

\makeatother

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}{0pt}
        Привет "--- мир

        Привет "--= мир
    \end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Putting the code inside `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` after `\begin{document}` solves the problem. This is caused by the fact that `babel` makes characters active after the beginning of the document, so my redefinition of `\cdash` is redefined back.

Comment: If you solved it, please consider making an answer to your own question :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the code inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` after `\begin{document}` solves the problem. This is caused by the fact that babel makes characters active after the beginning of the document, using `\AtBeginDocument` so the redefinition of \cdash is redefined back.

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{russian}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX}

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Georgia}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{
    %
    \renewcommand{\cdash}[3]{%
        \def\tempx@{#3}%
        \def\tempa@{-}%
        \def\tempb@{~}%
        \def\tempc@{*}%
        \def\tempd@{=}%
        %
        \ifx\tempx@\tempa@\@Acdash\else%
            \ifx\tempx@\tempb@\@Bcdash\else%
                \ifx\tempx@\tempc@\@Ccdash\else%
                    \ifx\tempx@\tempd@\@Dcdash\else%
                        \errmessage{Wrong usage of cdash}%
                    \fi%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi}
    %
    \renewcommand{\@Acdash}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
    \cyrdash\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
    %
    \renewcommand{\@Bcdash}{\leavevmode\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi
        \nobreak\cyrdash\penalty\exhyphenpenalty\hskip\z@skip\ignorespaces}%
    \renewcommand{\@Ccdash}{\leavevmode
        \nobreak\cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.35em\ignorespaces}%
    \newcommand{\@Dcdash}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
        \cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}



    \begin{minipage}{0pt}
        Привет "--- мир

        Привет "--= мир
    \end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]